# Set dual boot up on MacBook Pro 2019, but I'm unable to install ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, macbook

I’m an SE trying to set up a new work environment and it’s been decided I must set up my MacBook Pro 2019 16” (running MacOS Catalina 10.15.5) to dual boot ubuntu.

so I flashed ubuntu20.04.iso to an flash driver with Etcher (checked this was done correctly), installed rEFInd according to the specifications of my MacBook Pro 2019 and am able to successfully turn on my MacBook and meet the refind menu screen where my options are to boot either into macOS X or ubuntu. I am able to boot into ubuntu, however once I get to the installation screen and regain mouse control via usb mouse, I am unable to click the "install ubuntu" button. I can click it, it just doesn't actually select it. I am able to click other things, ie change installation language. When I click "install" the cursor temporarily turns into a loading cursor, then back to normal and nothing happens. then any other clicks on the install button don't even make the cursor change to a loading wheel. I'm thinking I need to reinstall refind w the ext4fs driver, but if there is any other insight out there it would be helpful.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting and running the installation again? 
Also, This problem cant be caused by drivers! This could simply be an issue with the USB!

Please tell me if the fallowing links help:

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2085375

Comment: did you verify the integrity/checksum of the .ISO before flashing it?

Comment: Hi Nmath, I just checked both (following https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#6-check-the-iso) and they both check out. apologies for the late response